# Adding the Custom links under dropdown toggle my account dashboard section in magento2

Tags: magento2, dashboard

Can anyone help me how to add customly added myaccount dashboard links in a Toggle section in magento2

Please find the screenshot.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: can you add more detail with snapshot where you want to add custom link?

Comment: Please share screenshot with more details.

Comment: Please find the screen shot in updated question, i would like to add all test links under test as toggle dropdown.

Comment: check this link http://gworks.mobi/blog/2016/05/17/mymail-custom-tab-in-customer-dashboard/ and this one https://www.dckap.com/blog/tab-in-customer-admin-in-magento-2/

Comment: Hi @Hitesh Thanks for your relpy, i have added links already, but i would like add all custom links under one dropdown

Answer (score 1):

I have did this by following steps:

1. Create one phtml file `ex. links.phtml`
2. call that phtml file in `customer_account.xml` in `customer_account_navigation` block.

[image]

Now you can achieve your things by phtml file

Comment: Hi @Mukesh thanks for your answer, its not dropdown i need like toggle section, for every link i have created a seperate test1_customer_index.xml, in that file i called seperate .phtml file.

Comment: I have 5 index.xml file like above and respected phtml files

Comment: How to include all under one Test toggle section